# How maximum period for linear congruential generator works

Tags: elementary-number-theory, random

I am learning about Linear Congruential Generators. I came across conditions for maximum cycle:

For X<sub>n</sub> = (a*X<sub>n-1</sub>+c) mod m, maximum cycle is achieved when:

1. c is relatively prime to m
2. m = 2<sup>b</sup> ,for some integer b
3. a = 1 + 4*k ,for some integer k

But I don't understand how these conditions came into place. I'm finding it difficult to understand how recursive "mod" operation works. I tried to read the [original paper](http://chagall.med.cornell.edu/BioinfoCourse/PDFs/Lecture4/random_number_generator.pdf) discussing these conditions, but was not able to understand (thanks to the cryptic explanation). Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Those conditions are only an example. The necessary and sufficient conditions are given by Theorem 1 (page 233). These conditions in your question satisfy Theorem 1 because $c$ is relatively prime to $m$, the only prime factors of $m$ is $2$ and when $4$ divides $m$ you have that the remainder of $a$ after division by $4$ is $1$. Would it also be your question why Theorem 1 is true?

Comment: Complete, understandable discussion in Knuth's "Seminumerical algoriths", chapter 3 (yes, almost a third of that tome). Heavy going.